# $\|X\beta\|_2\leq\|\beta\|_1\|X\| $ What inequality is this?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, optimization, normed-spaces

It is assumed $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p$ and $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$

The norm on $X$ is defined as $\|X\|=\max_{i\in\{1,\dots,p\}} \|X_{\cdot,i}\|_2=\max_{i\in\{1,\dots,p\}}(X^TX)_{ii}^{1/2}$.

What is the name of this norm? and what is the name of the inequality used to show

$\|X\beta\|_2=\|\sum_{i=1}^{p} X_{\cdot,i}\beta_i\|_2\leq\|\beta\|_1\|X\| $